# Is there any other way to do colour classification other than H S V conversion or using In range function

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

Actually I am working on classifying the  colours within a traffic panel ,tried with converting to Y Cb Cr space and use minimum Euclidean distance to classify the colour by matching from a dictionary that is predefined with the constant values,can anyone help me solve this problem .like is there any other approach to go with this.

```
import math
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
path="red"
for i in range(1,30):
    file=str(path)+str(i)+").jpg"
    im=cv2.imread(str(file))

    def gammaCorrection(src, gamma):
        invGamma = 1 / gamma
 
        table = [((i / 255) ** invGamma) * 255 for i in range(256)]
        table = np.array(table, np.uint8)
 
        return cv2.LUT(src, table)
    im= gammaCorrection(im, 1.5)
    lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)


   
    pixlst=[]
    r,c,ch=lab_image.shape

    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            val=lab_image[i][j]
            pixlst.append(val)
        

    lut2={"BLACK":[16,128,128],"RED":[81,240,90],"GREEN":[145,34,54],"BLUE":[41,110,240],"YELLOW":[210,146,7]}
    colorlist=[]
    for i in range(len(pixlst)):
        mindist=0
        val1=pixlst[i]
        x1=val1[0]
        y1=val1[1]
        z1=val1[2]
        for key in lut2.keys():
            i=1
            j=1
        
            val2=lut2[key]
            x2=val2[0]
            y2=val2[1]
            z2=val2[2]
            dist=math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2+(z1-z2)**2)
        
            if mindist==0:
                mindist=dist
                refkey=str(key)
            
            
            elif mindist!=0:
                if dist<mindist:
                    mindist=dist
            
                    refkey=str(key)
               
    
        color=str(refkey)
   
        colorlist.append(color)
    blackc=0
    bluec=0
    redc=0
    yellowc=0
    orangec=0
    greenc=0
    for i in range(len(colorlist)):
        if colorlist[i]=="RED":
            redc=redc+1
        if colorlist[i]=="GREEN":
            greenc=greenc+1
        if colorlist[i]=="YELLOW":
            yellowc=yellowc+1
        if colorlist[i]=="BLUE":
            bluec=bluec+1
        if colorlist[i]=="ORANGE":
            orangec=orangec+1
        if colorlist[i]=="BLACK":
            blackc=blackc+1


    if blackc!=0 and redc==0 and greenc==0 and yellowc==0 and bluec==0:
        print("color= BLACK")
    elif redc>greenc and redc>bluec and redc>yellowc:
        print("color= RED")
    elif greenc>redc and greenc>bluec and greenc>yellowc:
        print("color= GREEN")
    elif bluec>redc and bluec>greenc and bluec>yellowc:
        print("color= BLUE")

    elif yellowc>redc and yellowc>greenc and bluec<yellowc:
        print("color= YELLOW")
```

Comment: Why not Euclidean distance in RGB space? Why do you think YCbCr is more suited?

Comment: as the documentations i have gone through ,RGB is not suitable for images in different weather conditions like rainy,day ,night .so thought of YCbCr to use.